# interrupted waiting to send rpc request to server

Tags: hive, log4j2

We have faced this warning message every second in the hive log running continuously on one thread.

> interrupted waiting to send rpc request to server

However, the hive query execution is happening without any problem.

Why do hive logs getting exhausted with this message?

We solved this issue by restarting the hive server, could not figure out actual root cause of this issue and how to improve in order to avoid in the future.

In order to avoid this type of error, I am trying to add this setting in hive-log4j2.properties, however none of them worked.
First trial:

```
appender.DRFA.filter.burst.type = BurstFilter
appender.DRFA.filter.burst.onMatch = DENY
appender.DRFA.filter.burst.onMisMatch = NEUTRAL
appender.DRFA.filter.burst.level = WARN
appender.DRFA.filter.burst.rate = 2
appender.DRFA.filter.burst.maxBurst = 5
```

Second trail:

```
appender.DRFA.filter.myfilter.type = RegexFilter
appender.DRFA.filter.myfilter.regex = .*Database does not exist: databases.*
appender.DRFA.filter.myfilter.onMatch = DENY
appender.DRFA.filter.myfilter.onMisMatch = ACCEPT
```

Comment: finally, i was able to achieve ignoring the message by parsing the correct message instead of random message from the log using regexFilter. The correct message can be choosen by understanding the appender file pattern from properties file. i was able to achieve it using properties file itself.